# What is the proper way to manipulate dynamically imported components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, es6-modules

I've created a wrapper-like component for a library that I use. By wrapper-like what I mean is that my component wraps their component allowing me to set some arbitrary parameters or script ( kind of like a middle man.

Their component has about 100 components that you call directly as illustrated below,

```
import { Comp1, Comp2 } from "their-component"

return ( 
    <>
        <Comp1 color="red" width="100%" height="100%" />
        <Comp2 color="blue" width="50%"  height="100%" />
    </>
)
```

My "wrapper" allows me to do something along these line

```
import Wrapper from "their-component"

return(
    <> 
        <wrapper component="Comp1" color="red" width="100%" height="100%" />
        <wrapper component="Comp2" color="blue" width="100%" height="100%" />
    </>
)
```

Here is some pseudocode that shows what wrapper looks like and how it's being used.

```
"use client"

import React, { FC } from 'react'
// ComponentObjects are Comp1, Comp2, ... Comp49,Comp50
// from the examples above,
import * as ComponentObjects from './wrapper'

export default async function (props: any) {

    // get component.props from the props "<wrapper component="..." /> 
    let RequestedComp:any = ComponentObjects[
        props.component as keyof typeof ComponentObjects
    ]

    let modifier = props.modifier || 0

    return (
        <div id="wrapper">

            <!-- Create the imported ReactNode and forward the
                 proper parameters / props to it minues the props 
                 that wrapper uses to initialize the componen -->
            <RequestedComp width={props.width} height={props.height} color={props.color}/>

            <script>
                // this script dynamically changes html attributes
                // of the imported component. elaboration
                // below.
                [...document.querySelectorAll('.items')].forEach(s => {
                    let _attr = s.getAttribute('data-attr')
                    s.setAttribute('data-attr', _attr + modifer)
                })

            </script>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Each component that "their-component" imports has various attributes that I need to change. data-foo, data-bar, data-x. I could modify each component so that foo,bar, and x are all props that can be passed... however, if I where to do this, the work would have to be redone for each update or everytime a new child component gets added to their library.

update:

as of this moment I've added the "script" to a useEffect call and it seems to work. But I'm not sure if this is the best way to modify the attributes.

In clarifying my questions; it appears that I've actually deleted the question itself - The question is would this be a proper implementation in react/nextjs or would there be a more appropriate way to go about injecting javascript into their components or would modifying their components be the proper way to go about this?  In its basic form; I'm unsure of the direction to move in due to being a novice with react and don't want to start off with bad habits.

Comment: What you're calling a wrapper is just a module that re exports some other modules. There's nothing dynamic or lazy about it.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "*pass data to hundreds of different components of the same structure*", or where the "*interface is a reserved key word*" error message comes from

Comment: I guess "*`import Wrapper from "their-component";`*" should actually be `import wrapper from "my-wrapper-component";`, and "*`import * as ComponentObjects from './wrapper'`*" should be `import * as ComponentObjects from 'their-components';`?

Comment: "*I could modify each component so that foo,bar, and x are all props that can be passed...*" - yes, that would be the proper approach to solve this. Have you talked to the author/maintainer of the library about how this could be done, or if they saw another solution to support your use case?